# Mongodb: Join Documents in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

i want to lookup a object id in an array in which every element of the array cointans an object in which an id is included which refers to another document in another collection and an string field, it looks like this:

[image]

i want now to make a lookup over all objects in the array ingredients and replace the id field with th actual document of antoher collection.
My current solution gives me the first element and delets the others, the query looks like this:

```
              {$unwind: "$meal"},
              {$unwind: "$meal.ingredients"},                  
              { $lookup:
               {
                 from: 'ingredients',
                 localField: 'meal.ingredients.id',
                 foreignField: '_id',
                 as: "meal.ingredients.id"
               }}
```

The query delets the other 3 elements and just replaces the first object.id in the array with the actual document.

[image]

I hope someone knows the problem or faced the same issues and can help me.

Comment: Are the dcreenshot not visible? Because i dont have the collection.

Comment: The screenshots are horrible. Please use the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/) and copy the "text" of the documents in JSON representation. People cannot use the data from "pictures" in order to reproduce. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more detail on what should be in your question. But we should have sufficient data to produce a demonstrated "desired result" and ideally your current attempts and what is wrong presently that you do not understand.